# VAR thevalue = $.function(myownfunction); ? wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using a jquery function as a variable in my javascript file .

```
var thevalue = $.function(myownfunction);
```

but when i run it and firebug tells me that **$.function(myownfunction);** is not a function.
The function fetches a value and i want to change it into a VAR so other functions can use this variable instead of repeating the fetch.

p/s $.function(myownfunction); is just an example .

Have a nice day and thanks.

Comment: Where is the variable name? Are you forgot it?

Comment: i want to assign this variable to this function which fetches a value.

Comment: sorry about that , i forgot to put in the variable name. lol

Comment: Wow, this question is so vague. How are you setting up your function to be available as `$.function`?

Comment: Also, if your code isn't working, don't show us some brand new code where the names are different and you missed out some lines that you didn't think were important. If it's not working, chances are either the names *are* important or that other code *does* matter - let's see it all! :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var func = myfunction;
```

where

```
function myfunction() {}
```

or

```
myfunction = function() {}
```

Answer (score 2):

The property is not a function at the time you try to call it. It is probably `undefined` and you need to reorder your code.

> `$.function(myownfunction); is just an example .`

Please give real examples. `var` and `function` are reserved in JS.

Comment: @jAndy — you still shouldn't do it though, its confusing at best.

Answer (score 2):

To assign the return value of a function to a variable for later use:

```
var myVariable = myFunction(myArgument);
```

To assign a function to a variable:

```
var myFunctionAlias = myFunction;
```

You can then call `myFunctionAlias(myArgument)` exactly as you would call `myFunction(myArgument)`.

Therefore, if you want to assign a jquery function to a variable:

```
var myFunctionAlias = $.jQueryFunction;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var myownfunction = function(){};
```

Answer (score 1):

works for me 
http://jsfiddle.net/PchXC/

```
function who(){
return "#vivek"
}

alert( $(who()).html());

<div id="vivek">
    hi
</div>
```